# meaning of `in vollem Tagen`

Tags: meaning

I translate

> Es währte nicht lang, so kam ein Herr in einem Wagen dahergerennt in
>   vollem Tagen

into

> It didn't last long, so a man came in a wagon running that way in less
>   than a day.

How should I interpret `in vollem Tagen`? Is it just `in full day`? or is it connect to `nicht lang` or `so`? I don't understand the nuance.

This is from https://www.grimmstories.com/de/grimm_maerchen/die_drei_brueder

Comment: This appears to be a reading (or OCR?) problem: It actually says *... in vollem Jagen ...*. See the following sentence.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because asking about simple typos and OCR failures isn't useful for future research.

Comment: also see https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/655/how-to-handle-typos-that-are-significant-in-respect-to-why-the-question-came-up

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a typo. The correct version is:

> Es währte nicht lang, so kam ein Herr in einem Wagen dahergerennt in vollem **J**agen.
>
> It didn't last long, so a man came running in a wagon running **in full race**.

»Jagen« (here used as a noun, but normally a verb) means: to hunt, but also to rush or to race.

- [source 1](http://gutenberg.spiegel.de/buch/-6248/1)
- [source 2](http://weiterlesen.de/Leseprobe/Die-schoensten-Kinder-und-Hausmaerchen/9783736842267/html)

Comment: Wow thank you so much. There are many misinfo on the web.

Comment: Except in good English you would not say "running" or "in full race".

Comment: Better: "Before long a gentleman drove up at full speed."